# Is OpenSSL 0.9.8h affected by CVE-2014-0195?

Tags: security, openssl, dtls

I have spent time on finding out if OpenSSL 098h is affected by the CVE-2014-0195 ..but it seems I will have to understand the entire file d1_both.c to answer this question.

1) Preliminary look at patch released looks like 0.9.8h is not vulnerable to above CVE since all the fragment reassembly stuff was addded in 0.9.8o. And the patch is all about fragment reassembly.

The function dtls1_reassembly_fragment() is missing in 098h, so one may assume we are okay

2) But closer examination show that bug is about not checking the
'actual size of fragment' against the 'fragment length stored in the header of fragment'

Any help is much appreciated while I continue with the understanding the code flow.

Comment: How do I get the fix for this vulnerability on top of 098h if I don't want to upgrade to 098za which has patch for it?

Comment: What prevents you from upgrading to the latest 0.9.8? All good distros should have the security update.

Comment: Legacy code uses OpenSSL APIs after wrapping them up; to switch to OpenSSL latest version while sticking to the principles (for which wrappers have been written) will be big task

Comment: After analysis it looks to me that openssl 098h is not vulnerable here, since the fix is about taking care while reading buffered messages inside 'SSL s*'. In 098h they never try to find the msg sequence num inside buffered msgs.  In 098o onwards they look back to buffered msg when a) they have out of sequence msg b) they have frag_len < msg_len for a message

Comment: I don't have experience with developing with openssl but I would have thought the 0.9.8 line should have a near stable API. But then I've heard how horrible openssl api is.

Comment: Dear ekcr1, Thank you for all the help with this question :) .. Appreciate it

Comment: My analysis suggests that this vulnerability does not affect OpenSSL 098h

Comment: No problem, glad I can contribute :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities.html published 23th June 2014 .. OpenSSL 0.9.8h is not affected by CVE-2014-0195.

Only OpenSSL version 0.9.8o & above are affected

Answer (score 1):

According to http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-0195 0.9.8h is a vulnerable version. I would probably trust the advisory more than my code intropection skills :)

Comment: This note from OpenSSL claims that 0.9.8e is also affected but note from RedHat states contradictory statement 098e not being affected.

Comment: refer comment 11 in the link below from Thomas Hager

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't suffer from the issue, but it's probably better safe than sorry. 0.9.8h was released six years ago and may have other security issues.